# Links in Site Pages Library: Get using Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, sitepages

I am working on SharePoint Online. Inside the 'Site Pages' library, I have created a few site Pages and I also create a 'Link' item using the New > Links option. I use the 'Link' to connect to a page in SharePoint. After the link item is created, the Name of the Link is 'sample.Url'. When I click on the link from SharePoint, it takes me to the page associated with the link.

My issue is that, I try to get the items in Site Pages library using Rest API and display as a tree view in my SPFx web part. But inside the web part, if I click on the link, it just download the page.

Can any one help to resolve the issue. Is there any way I can use REST API to get the actual URL I gave in SharePoint while creating the field?

This is the API I used to get the items

```
const url = subPageUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site%20Pages')/items?$select=Title,FileDirRef,File_x0020_Type,EncodedAbsUrl,FileRef,FileLeafRef"
```

Comment: Can you show us the code generated in the browser by the SPFX part for the link to the Site Page?  Thanks

Comment: Which endpoint are you using to fetch the site page items? can you show us the code you used or the response you get from API call?

Comment: I updated the question with the API I used

Answer (score 2):

You can use below endpoint to get the actual web page URL you provided while creating a link page:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/SP.Utilities.ShortcutLink.GetShortcutLink(@a1)?@a1='https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/SitePages/googlehome.url'
```

Where `@a1` is the URL of shortcut link name, like `sample.Url` in your case.

**Sample output**:

```
<m:properties>
    <d:siteId m:type="Edm.Guid">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:siteId>
    <d:uniqueId m:type="Edm.Guid">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:uniqueId>
    <d:url>http://google.com/</d:url>
    <d:webId m:type="Edm.Guid">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:webId>
</m:properties>
```

Where `url` is the actual web page URL you provided while creating a link page.

Comment: Thanks! I am able to get the Url using this API. Just wanted to ask one more thing, because i am getting the items inside the Site Page library using the below API

<siteurl> + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site%20Pages')/items?$select=*"

Is there any way i can get this shortcut link using the select keyword?

Comment: I think you got the answer already. Glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers! I managed to get the shortcut link using the same API

```
  const url =
  subPageUrl +
  "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site%20Pages')/items?$select=Properties/vti_x005f_shortcuturl&$expand=Properties"
```

This gives me the url and also the shortcut link.